# How to use feature toggles in SAP Webi

Tags: business-objects, webi

As of 4.3 SP4 feature toggles can be defined in the CMC. I am not familiar with these toggles and documentation is scares.
Where can I find the available feature toggles and how do I use those in a WebI report?

I cannot find any reference to a toggle in the create variable window.
A real life example would be great.

Thx,

Comment: You may get more engagement on your question [here](https://bobj-board.org/). Stack Overflow is more about pure code.